# Is there any official contract for the Iterable interface with respect to multiple usage?

Tags: java, iterable

Since Java 5, we have the new [`java.lang.Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) type that can be used in foreach loops as such:

```
for (Object element : iterable);
```

The [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) contract does not specify whether its [`iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator%28%29) method can be called more than once before disposing of the Iterable. I.e., it is not clear whether the following can be expected to work for all `Iterables`:

```
for (Object element : iterable);
for (Object element : iterable);
```

For instance, an `Iterator` wrapping implementation cannot be used twice:

```
public class OneShotIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private final Iterator<T> it;

    public OneShotIterable(Iterator<T> it) {
        this.it = it;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return it;
    }
}
```

For most `Iterables`, this is irrelevant, as they are in fact retro-fitted Collection API types such as `List`, `Set`, which already have well-defined contracts for their `iterator()` methods.

My question is: Is my `OneShotIterable` implementation violating some contract that I'm overlooking? In other words, will users of an `Iterable` expect it to be reusable? If so, is there an "official" recommendation by the Java 5 expert group how to deal with such "one shot" `Iterables` (e.g. throw an `IllegalStateException` on a second call)?

Comment: Couldn't you just increment a field of your OneShotIterable each time iterator() get called, and throw an exception if it's gte n?

Comment: @LukasEder doh you edited it away

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One precedent that I could find in the standard library is the [`DirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) interface.

Its Javadoc contains the following passage (emphasis theirs):

> **While `DirectoryStream` extends `Iterable`, it is not a general-purpose `Iterable` as it supports only a single `Iterator`; invoking the `iterator` method to obtain a second or subsequent iterator throws `IllegalStateException`.**

To me, this suggests two things:

- The implied contract on [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) is that you're supposed to be able to iterate more than once (perhaps even concurrently!)
- A **boldface** warning in the documentation coupled with throwing [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) is probably the best way to handle non-compliance in your own classes/interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to my question, but Apache Commons Collections has addressed this issue in its `IteratorUtils` class:

- [`IteratorUtils.asIterable(Iterator)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IteratorUtils.html#asIterable-java.util.Iterator-)
- [`IteratorUtils.asMultipleUseIterable(Iterator)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IteratorUtils.html#asMultipleUseIterable-java.util.Iterator-)

Both are factory methods for the `IteratorIterable` type. The above distinction makes it clear that one must take care when wrapping `Iterators` in `Iterables`.